# Continuity of functions containing greatest integer function

Tags: analysis, continuity

I need help with this problem:

> For all $x \ge \frac{1}{2}$  let $f(x)=[x]+(x-[x])^{[x]}$. 
>   Prove that $f(x)$ is continuous and increasing on $[1,+\infty[$.

I've been given this hint but still I don't really understand it:

> We got :
>   \begin{equation}
>   f(x)=\begin{cases}
>     1  & \text{, if $x \in [\frac{1}{2},1[ $}\\
>     n + (x - n)^n & \text{, if $x \in [n,n+1[, n \in \mathbb{N}^*$}
>   \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

Even with this hint in hand I still don't know how to start it.

Comment: Your $f$ is continuous in each interval in which $[1/2, +\infty[$ is partitioned; therefore you have only to check continuity in the junction points between two consecutive intervals, e.g. in $x=1$, $x=2$, and so on. How can you prove (or disprove) that $f$ is continuous in $1$? And in $2$? Can you generalize?

Comment: I mistaken , the question is "prove that f(x) is continuous and strictly increasing"

Comment: @14max : he means "continuous at x=1 and at x=2"

Comment: Consider $f(n-\epsilon)$ and $f(n+\epsilon)$

Comment: @MPW: Yup! I was writing in a hurry... Sorry for the typo. BTW, see my answer below. ;-)

Comment: Very very sorry ,the inteval is [n,n+1[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=i+d$ (integer and decimal part). The function is
$$i+d^i.$$

Between two integers, this is a continuous function (a polynomial).

For $x\to i^-$, $f(x)\to i-1+1=i$, and for $x\to i^+$, $f(x)\to i+0=i$. Thus the function is continuous for all $x>0$.

Now for $i\ge0$, $d^i$ is an increasing function, so that by continuity, $f(x)$ is increasing for all $x>0$ (constant in $(0,1]$).

[image]

Comment: Is this the original function?

Answer (score 0):

Greatest integer function is a typical example of function defined by separating cases. This means that:

$$[x] = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{, if } 0\leq x < 1 \\ 1 &\text{, if } 1 \leq x < 2 \\ \vdots \\ n-1 &\text{, if } n-1\leq x < n \\ n &\text{, if } n\leq x < n+1 \\ \vdots \end{cases}\; .$$

Therefore also your function $f$ can be described in the same manner, i.e. by separating cases: you get:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0+(x-0)^0 & \text{, if } 1/2\leq x < 1 \\ 1 + (x-1)^1 &\text{, if } 1 \leq x < 2 \\ 2 + (x-2)^2 &\text{, if } 2\leq x < 3\\ \vdots \\ n-1 + (x-n+1)^{n-1} &\text{, if } n-1\leq x < n \\ n + (x-n)^n &\text{, if } n\leq x < n+1 \\ \vdots \end{cases}\; .$$

From this representation, you see that $f$ is continuous in $[1/2,1[$ and in each open interval $]1,2[$, $]2,3[$, ..., $]n-1,n[$, $]n,n+1[$... So you have only to prove that $f$ is continuous at each point $1$, $2$, $3$, ... $n$,...

Let us try to prove if $f$ is continuous in $1$. We can write the continuity condition at $x=1$ as:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = f(1) \qquad \text{AND}\qquad \lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x) = f(1)\; .$$

Therefore we have to evaluate two directional limits and the value of $f$ in $1$. The value of $f$ in $1$ is given by:

$$f(1) = \Big. 1 + (x - 1)^1\Big|_{x=1} = 1 \; ;$$

on the other hand, we have:

$$\begin{split} \lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to 1,\ x<1} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1} 1 = 1 \\ \lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to 1,\ 1< x < 2} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1} 1 + (x-1)^1 = 1 \end{split}$$

hence $f$ is continuous at the point $1$.

Analogously, for the continuity at $x=2$ we have to check if:

$$\lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x) = f(2) \qquad \text{AND}\qquad \lim_{x\to 2^+} f(x) = f(2)\; .$$

The value of $f$ in $2$ is given by:

$$f(2) = \Big. 2 + (x-2)^2\Big|_{x=2} = 2 \; ;$$

on the other hand, we have:

$$\begin{split} \lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to 2,\ 1<x<2} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1} 1 + (x - 1)^1 = 1+1=2 \\ \lim_{x\to 2^+} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to 2,\ 2< x < 3} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 2} 2 + (x - 2)^2 = 2 \end{split}$$

hence $f$ is continuous at the point $2$ also.

The same reasoning applies in the general case $x=n$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. In fact, we have $f(n)=n$ and:

$$\begin{split} \lim_{x\to n^-} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to n,\ n-1<x<n} f(x) = \lim_{x\to n} (n-1) + (x - (n-1))^{n-1} = (n-1)+1=n \\ \lim_{x\to n^+} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to n,\ n< x < n+1} f(x) = \lim_{x\to n} n + (x - n)^n = n \end{split}$$

thus $f$ is continuous at any $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

---

Coming to monotonicity, it suffices to prove that $f$ increases strictly in each interval in which $[1,+\infty[$ is divided.
Since $f$ is differentiable in each of these intervals and continuous everywhere, it suffices to show that $f^\prime (x)> 0$ inside each interval.
The derivative of $f$ is:

$$f^\prime (x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{, if } 1/2 < x <1 \\ n(x-n)^{n-1} &\text{, if } n<x<n+1,\ n \in \mathbb{N}^* \end{cases}$$

and it is clearly $>0$ on each interval $]n,n+1[$. Therefore $f$ increases strictly on the whole of $[1,+\infty[$.

Comment: Yep,I quite understand your answer but you know my problem  is how do we get all of this proof from this original function " f(x)=[x] +(x-[x])$^[$$^x$$^]$ ,I lack the knowledge about the properties of functions with greatest integer functions

Comment: Greatest integer function is a typical example of function defined by separating cases. That is, $[x] = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{, if } 0\leq x < 1 \\ 1 &\text{, if } 1 \leq x < 2 \\ \vdots \\ n-1 &\text{, if } n-1\leq x < n \\ n &\text{, if } n\leq x < n+1 \\ \vdots \end{cases}$. This fact affects the definition of your $f$, because it too can be written by separating cases; this should explain the hint you've been given.

Comment: One last thing ,how can we affect the original function from this definition of [x] ?I almost get it but not entirely ,I need more detailed explanation please

Comment: Do you think we can solve it with "epsilon-delta"  proof ?I'm just curious ,I just want as many solution as possible ,so that it will be 100 % crystal clear

Comment: Very very sorry ,the interval is [n,n+1[

Comment: I'll answer your question about $[x]$ and $f(x)$ ASAP, editing my answer above.